# Accessing a vector iterator by index?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, dereference, random-access

Recently I came across this code in my codebase (Simplified for here, of course)

```
auto toDelete = std::make_shared<std::string>("FooBar");
std::vector<decltype(toDelete)> myVec{toDelete};
auto iter = std::find_if(std::begin(myVec), std::end(myVec), 
   [](const decltype(toDelete) _next)
   {
      return *_next == "FooBar";
   });

if (iter != std::end(myVec))
{
   std::shared_ptr<std::string> deletedString = iter[0];
   std::cout << *deletedString;
   myVec.erase(iter);
}
```

[Online Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34b34c727341c25f)

Now, I noticed that here we are accessing an iterator by indexing!

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> deletedString = iter[0];
```

I've never seen anyone access an iterator by indexing before, so all I can guess at is that the iterator gets treated like a pointer, and then we access the first element pointed to at the pointer. So is that code actually equivalent to:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> deletedString = *iter;
```

Or is it Undefined Behavior?

Comment: `x[y]` is (in this case) precisely the same as `*(x+y)`. Adding zero to the iterator doesn't change it. So `iter[0]` is the same as `*iter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) for RandomAccessIterator:

> Expression: `i[n]`
>
> Operational semantics: `*(i+n)`

Since a `std::vector`'s iterators meet the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, indexing them is equivalent to addition and dereferencing, like an ordinary pointer. `iter[0]` is equivalent to `*(iter+0)`, or `*iter`.

Answer (score 4):

This is [**Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) conforming behavior

> **24.2.7 Random access iterators [random.access.iterators]**
>
> 1 A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a random access iterator
>   if, in addition to satisfying the requirements for bidirectional
>   iterators, the following expressions are valid as shown in Table 118.
>
> `a[n]` convertible to reference: `*(a + n)`

Note that it is **not** required that the particular iterator is implemented as a pointer. Any iterator class with an overloaded `operator[]`, `operator*` and `operator+` with the above semantics will work. For `std::vector`, the iterator category is random access iterator, and it it **required** to work.